# RemoteWebDriver launches browsers in background when started remotely using cygwin and openssh

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cygwin, selenium-grid, openssh, remotewebdriver

I am trying to run automation tests remotely on a windows machine using from Unix box. I am using cygwin and openssh for it.

> I am able to run the tests and take screenshots. However, the browsers launch and run in the background.
>   
>   I cannot change the property of the CYGWIN SSHD service to "Allow interaction with desktop" because I cannot use the Local system account.

Is there any other way to be able to view the UI in the remote window machine while execution is going on?